# jquery - Add class based on vertical scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a single page portfolio site and would like to add a class to each nav element when the user scrolls to that section on the page.

http://www.legworkstudio.com/ uses this function on their site but I can't find the jQuery snippet for reference.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be wanting Jquery Waypoints to do this.
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scrollTop()` and compare it to the offset of a section using 'offset()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a jquery plugin. scrollClass.js does exactly what you need. https://github.com/virgiliud/scrollClass.js